# Is there any function in Wordpress for set title

Tags: wordpress

I want to know is there any function for the set title in WordPress. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Set title of what? Page/post title? Site title?

Comment: set title for the website. I can modify it manually but I want to change through the functions.php file. Is there any function regarding this?

Comment: I put an answer in

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not easy function for this. You can use the `$wpdb` object to accomplish this and update the "blogname" option. Definitely use the helper functions and avoid running queries on the database directly. The `update` helper function forces you to specify "WHERE" clauses, which helps prevent you from completely screwing up your DB.

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->update(
     "{$wpdb->prefix}options",
     array(
         'option_value' => 'New blog title'
     ),
     array(
         'option_name' => 'blogname'
     ),
     array(
         '%s'
     ),
     array(
         '%s'
     )
);
```

I would read up on `$wpdb` before messing with it, to make sure you are running safe operation. And as always, use a test environment first: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/

Comment: Did this answer your question? Happy to help further if you need.